# Extracting financial data on python - google colab

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I'm running this code to get the data below, but this is taking a lot of time to load. Is there a more optimized way to run it better? P.S. I'm working on google colab.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import yfinance as yf
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

stocks = ['AYX', 'TEAM', 'DDOG', 'MDB', 'TDC', 'CFLT'\]

df = pd.DataFrame()

start_date = '2021-10-1'
current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=current_date, freq='M')
dates = [date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for date in date_range\]

for stock in stocks:
    for date in dates:
        # Loop through each date
        info = yf.Ticker(stock).info
        info1 = yf.Ticker(stock).fast_info
        NetDebt = info['totalDebt'] - info['totalCash']
        marketcap = info1['market_cap']
        asofDate = date
        df = df.append({
            'Date': asofDate,
            'Stock': stock,
            'NetDebt': NetDebt,
            'marketcap': marketcap,
            'EV': marketcap + NetDebt
        }, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

Comment: How long it takes and why you think it should not take so long?

Comment: It doesn't affect performance but why you import two times `yfinance` and three times `pandas` ?